# Loop through a column, while checking if cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through a column, while checking if cell in row is empty and if today's date minus date in table are higher or the same as 7. If requirements are met send email.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim myApp As Outlook.Application, mymail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim datum1 As Date
Dim datum2 As Long
Dim danasnji1 As Date
Dim danasnji2 As Long
Dim x As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lastrow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(x, 10).Value) Then
        x = x + 1
    Else
        datum1 = Cells(x, 10).Value
        datum2 = datum1
        danasnji1 = Date
        danasnji2 = danasnji1
    
        If danasnji2 - datum2 >= 7 Then
            Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
            Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            mymail.To = "examlemail@mail"
            With mymail
                .Subject = "Test"
                .body = "Body Code"
                .Send
            End With
            Cells(x, 10).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next
Set myApp = Nothing
Set mymail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Picture of Excel table column:
[image: Picture of excel table column]

This code sends email but the loop skips some cells. There should be 5 emails, but it sends 3. Cells that worked are coloured red.

Comment: remove the `x = x + 1`

Comment: First remove x = x + 1 never change a for variable just leave the if part empty for the moment

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, this change worked, script is now working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never** modify the counting variable (in your case `x`) inside the loop, it is incremented *automatically* by the `For`-statement.

In your case, you increment it additionally to the autoincrement, causing that the code skips a line when an "empty" line is found. Change your code to

```
For x = 2 To lastrow
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, 10).Value) Then
        datum1 = Cells(x, 10).Value
        datum2 = datum1
        danasnji1 = Date
        danasnji2 = danasnji1
    
        If danasnji2 - datum2 >= 7 Then
            Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
            Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            mymail.To = "examlemail@mail"
            With mymail
                .Subject = "Test"
                .body = "Body Code"
                .Send
            End With
            Cells(x, 10).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Note that you should qualify your `Cells` usages: Tell VBA with which worksheet you want to work with. If you write `IsEmpty(Cells(x, 10).Value)`, VBA will assume that you want to work with the active sheet, and that is not always what you want. Have a close look to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, this change worked, script is now working as intended.